# How to format hash values to comma separated text in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash like:

```
hash = {0 => ["a","b", "c"], 1 => ["x", "y", "z"]}
```

I would like to format this hash so that every array will be on a new line and the elements without quotes, separated by comma:

```
a, b, c
x, y, z
```

I've tried:

```
array = hash.values
#=> [["a","b", "c"], ["x", "y", "z"]]

array.each.join(", ")
#=> "a, b, c, x, y, z"
```

But there's an extra comma after `c`. How can I split the array into two lines?

Comment: If you're only worried about the output, you could use `puts` after joining each array.

Comment: Are you trying to generate CSV data?

Comment: I am actually rendering it in Rails)

Comment: @anndrew78 in that case `<br />` rather than `\n` might be what you are looking for as a "new line"

Comment: @engineersmnky do you have a nice example how to use <br/> in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it would be:

```
hash.values.each_with_object(""){ |v, str| str << "\n" << v.join(', ') }.strip
#=> "a, b, c\nx, y, z"
```

or:

```
hash.values.map{|v| v * ', ' } * "\n"
#=> "a, b, c\nx, y, z"
```

or:

```
hash.values.map{|v| v.join(', ') } * "\n"
#=> "a, b, c\nx, y, z"
```

Note that `\n` should be in double quotes(`"\n"`) for newline character to work.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to do CSV, don't try to homebrew it, it's trickier than it looks. For example, sometimes quotes are necessary.

```
require 'csv'
puts CSV.generate { |csv|
  hash.each_value { |row| csv << row }
}
# => a,b,c
#    x,y,z
```

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there, try the following,

```
hash.values.map{ |v| v.join(',') }.join("\n")
```